# Is intersection of refining locally connected topologies locally connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, $S(X)$ be the set of topologies in $X$, and

$$\mathcal{T}^P = \bigcap \{\mathcal{T}^* \in S(X) : \mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}^* \textrm{ and } (X, \mathcal{T}^*) \textrm{ is locally connected}\}.$$

Is $\mathcal{T}^P$ locally connected?

Notes:

- Discrete topology refines any topology and is locally connected, so the above intersection is well-defined.
- $\mathcal{T}^P$ is a topology in $X$ ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445017/51161))
- $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}^P$
- If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is locally connected, then $\mathcal{T}^P = \mathcal{T}$.
- If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is finite or finitely generated, then $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is locally connected.
- So a possible counter-example must have infinite $X$.
- [Quotient map preserves local connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2426794/51161).

It seems to me that there should be a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Given a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$, let $c(\mathcal{T})$ be topology in $X$ generated by the $\mathcal{T}$-connected components of all the $\mathcal{T}$-open subsets of $X$.  Then any locally connected topology $\mathcal{T}^*$ containing $\mathcal{T}$ must contain $c(\mathcal{T})$, since if $U$ is $\mathcal{T}$-open then each $\mathcal{T}$-connected component of $U$ is a union of $\mathcal{T}^*$-connected components of $U$ which are $\mathcal{T}^*$-open by local connectedness.  Also, if $\mathcal{T}=c(\mathcal{T})$, then $\mathcal{T}$ is locally connected, since the connected components of each element of $\mathcal{T}$ are in $c(\mathcal{T})$.

Now iterate this construction transfinitely.  That is, recursively define $c^\alpha(\mathcal{T})$ for each ordinal $\alpha$ by $c_0(\mathcal{T})=\mathcal{T}$, $c^{\alpha+1}(\mathcal{T})=c(c^{\alpha}(\mathcal{T}))$, and $c^\alpha(\mathcal{T})$ is the topology generated by $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}c^\beta(\mathcal{T})$ if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.  This defines an increasing sequence of topologies on $X$ which must eventually stabilize (since there are more ordinals than topologies on $X$).  That is, for some $\alpha$, $c(c^\alpha(\mathcal{T}))=c^\alpha(\mathcal{T})$.  Then $c^\alpha(\mathcal{T})$ is locally connected.  But also, any locally connected topology containing $\mathcal{T}$ contains $c^\beta(\mathcal{T})$ for all $\beta$ (by induction on $\beta$).  It follows that your $\mathcal{T}^P$ is equal to $c^\alpha(\mathcal{T})$ and is locally connected.

Comment: Wow. That is both unexpected and seriously awesome! Also a technique I have not seen used before. With this answer you may have provided my research an essential missing ingredient. I'll credit you.

Comment: I'll just add here the observation that the connected components of all open subsets of $c^{\alpha}(\mathcal{T})$ is a basis of $c^{\alpha + 1}(\mathcal{T})$.