# Is a topology recoverable from its set of neighborhoods?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $\tau$ be the set of opens.

Let's call a pair of the form $(x, W)$ where $x$ is a point in $X$ and $W$ is a (not necessarily open) neighborhood of $x$ a **neighborhood pair**.

Let's call the collection of all such neighborhood pairs $N$.

It seems pretty clear that we can convert back and forth between $(X, \tau)$ and $(X, N)$ without losing any information. An open set $U$ is a set that is a neighborhood of each of its points. The same token, a set $T$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if and only if it contains an open set $U$ that contains $x$.

I'm wondering what happens when you strip away the information about what point a neighborhood is a neighborhood of, i.e.

$$ N \rightsquigarrow \{ W : (x, W) \in N \} $$

Call $N$ the **set of neighborhoods** corresponding to the topological space in question.

**Can we recover our topology from just the set of neighborhoods, neglecting completely which points they are neighborhoods of?**.

---

We definitely have a way of getting **an** answer by just intersecting a ton of topologies.

Given a family of topologies $F$ over a shared point set $X$, $\cap F$ is a topology.

For proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445017/intersection-of-topologies).

Alternatively, let's check the axioms one at a time.

- $\varnothing$ is in $\cap F$.
- $X$ is in $\cap F$.
- if $A$ is in $\cap F$ and $B$ is in $\cap F$, then $A$ and $B$ are in each $\tau \in F$ individually, thus $A \cap B$ is in each $\tau$ individually, thus $A \cap B$ is in $\cap F$.
- Suppose $E \subset \cap F$, then $E \subset \tau$ for each $\tau$ in $F$. Thus $\cup E$ is in each $\tau$, thus $\cup E$ is in $\cap F$.

Suppose our set of neighborhoods is $M$.

Let $\Lambda$ be the family of all topologies on $X$.

Let $L \subset \Lambda$ be the family of all topologies on $X$ whose set of neighborhoods is a superset of $M$. $L$ is not empty. The discrete topology on $X$ will always be in $L$.

Let's call $\cap L$ $\sigma$. $\sigma$ is a topology.

There's no guarantee though that the set of neighborhoods of $(X, \sigma)$ will be $M$ though and no guarantee that $(X, \sigma)$ will be the topology we started with to produce $M$.

1. This construction always succeeds, regardless of whether it's possible to get a topology whose set of neighborhoods is $M$ or not.
2. If there are multiple topologies whose set of neighborhoods is $M$, this construction will give us the coarsest one.

Comment: This is not quite true @spaceisdarkgreen, for example in my answer below, the set $\{1, 2\}$ meets that requirement in the topology $\tau_1$, even though it is not open in $\tau_1$. The correct statement is that $O$ is open iff for every $x\in O$ there is neighborhood of $x$ such that $x\in W\subseteq O$, but that doesn't help in recovering a topology just from the set of neighborhoods.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**No.** Your set $N$, the neighborhoods, are just all possible supersets of non-empty open sets and this collection may coincide for different topologies. For example, let $X=\{1, 2, 3\}$ and consider the following topologies:

$$\tau_1=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, X\},$$
$$\tau_2=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, X\},$$
$$\tau_3=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, X\}.$$

Then for any one of the topologies the neighborhoods are just the sets that contain $1$. Another example would be the real line with the standard topology and the real line with the lower limit topology, i.e. where a basis of topology are the intervals $[a,b)$, $a<b\in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, one has
$$[a,b)\supseteq (a, b)$$
and
$$(a, b)\supseteq \left[a+ \frac{b-a}{2}, b\right)$$
for all $a<b\in \mathbb{R}$, showing that the supersets of the respective bases, which are the respective neighborhoods, coincide.

Comment: For your first example, how does the collection of neighbourhoods coincide? For, $\tau_1$ doesn't have the neighborhood $\{1,2\}$ where $\tau_2$ has. The 2nd example is alright.

Comment: @MAS: I struggle to understand how $\{1, 2\}$ avoids being a neighborhood of 1 in $\tau_1$, since it contains the open set $\{1\}$. But maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @Kevin, yes. Because by definition, a neighborhood $N$ of a point $p$ in a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is a set such that there is an open set $U$ of $X$ for which $p\in U \subset N$. Since $\{1,2\}$ is an open, it is a neighborhood of 1 by taking $U=N=\{1,2\}$. I don't see where I am wrong.

Comment: @MAS In both topologies, $N = \{1,2\}$ is a neighborhood of $p = 1$, as it contains the open set $U = \{1\}$ which contains $1$. Therefore, $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ both have neighborhoods $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, X\}$.

Comment: @Cecilia, thanks I see it now.

Comment: @Cecilia $\{1, 3\}$ is also a neighborhood for both.

Comment: @JonathanHole Indeed, I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 14):

A "neighborhood" is a set whose interior is nonempty. I guess you are asking if we can determine the topology on a set if we know which subsets have nonempty interiors, which is the same as knowing which subsets are dense: a set has nonempty interior iff its complement is not dense.

Consider two topologies on the set $X=[0,2\pi)$; the standard topology as a subspace of the real line, and the topology which makes the map $t\mapsto e^{it}$ a homeomorphism from $X$ to the unit circle. Plainly, these are two different topologies with the same dense sets and therefore the same "neighborhoods". A more exotic topology on $X$, still with the same dense sets, is the topology generated by the half-open intervals of the form $[a,b)$.

Comment: I edited my answer before I saw yours to include essentially the same example, so now it looks a bit weird. Oh well.